# DataList is not binding event after datatable is correct

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010

I have following datalist:

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlOrgImages" runat="server" 
                                    Width="100%" RepeatColumns="4" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <table width="98%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <asp:Image ID="imgLogo" ImageUrl='OrgImages/<%# Eval("Logo") %>' runat="server" />
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <asp:RadioButton ID="rdLogoSelect" runat="server" />
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:DataList>
```

I am binding it through code:

```
 private void BindOrgLogo()
    {
        dlOrgImages.DataSource= obj.GetDataTable("select idOrg,Title,Logo from Organization order by idOrg");
        dlOrgImages.DataBind();
    }
```

obj.GetDataTable(...) is giving me correct datatable.

But datalist is not getting bound. Its not showing me anything.

What can be the problem???

Please help me.

Comment: Do you get records from obj.GetDataTable?

Comment: @Adil yes sir, getting datatable from it

Comment: Getting dataTable is different from getting records in datatable, you may have zero records in datatable

Comment: @Adil yes sir, i am getting expected records in datatable from that function call... I debugged and seen it.

Comment: Check if any of parent container like div is visible and if you are getting any exception during data binding in event like RowDataBound

Comment: Check how the img is rendered in the browser using firebug. Find the image url generated and check if you can access the image direct using that imageurl. This will tell you if the correct url is getting generated.

Comment: @Narendra i checked that, but as datalist is not generating its not showing me anything, not even radio buttons

Comment: Check whether you have placed the DataList under UpdatePanel?

Comment: add databinding/itembinding event handler, and check if the event handler is getting called.

Comment: @thevan yes i have placed it... what to do in such case?

Comment: after binding the datalist, just update the updatepanel like UpdatePanel.Update();